# Pandas:speed diff for parameterised and non-parameterised query using pd.read_sql

Tags: python, pandas

I am fetching the data from from teradata ,using pd.read_sql() by passing formatted query ,where  parameters are already added.
but data loading in this case is slow .
Also tried using params option of pd.read_sql() , as parameterised runs like passedthrough sql on the server directly, but there is no difference i observed.

```
# non-parameterised approach
query = 'select emp_name salary from employee where empid > 2000 '

with teradatsql.connect(con_str) as td:
    df = pd.read_sql(query,td) 

# parameterised approch
with teradatsql.connect(con_str) as td:
    df = pd.read_sql('select emp_name salary from employee where empid > %(id)s',td,params={'id':'2000'})
```

does there is any other way to run query faster in pandas or am i missing something in passed through sql approach here like SAS has.

Comment: it's hard to say what might be limiting the performance of your query (data size/network io, indexing of SQL table, etc), but parameterized vs unparameterized query string almost certainly will have virtually no effect.

Comment: if you login to the server running your database and run the sql on the command line tool - what performance do you see?   It's most probable times are primarily how efficiently the SQL runs on terra data not a pandas point